# Database design for book structure (table of contents) and content

Tags: ios, sql, database, cocoa-touch

I have a list of entries, which can be thought of as paragraphs from a book, stored as separate objects of the same class. These objects have a ‘num’ property, along with the actual text, so that I know their order and can later display them in as a list in the correct order (1,2,3, …).

Now I want to bring this one step further and be able to ‘record’ the structure of the book, like the table of contents. In other words, say the book is divided into chapters, and each chapter is further divided into sections. The first few paragraphs are found under Ch.1 Sec.1, then Ch.1 Sec. 2, and so on all the way to Ch. n, S. m. What I’m not sure of is what’s a good way to record this information? I've been told that I should use a database with SQL but I'm not sure where to begin.

The implementation must allow me to ‘quickly’ determine the following two things at any point: (1) Given a chapter and section #, what paragraphs are contained within this section? (2) Given a paragraph #, which chapter and section is it under? It must also be flexible enough that I could use the same platform in the future with few edits if the structure (depth-wise) of the book changes (e.g. sections are divided into subsections, etc.). Finally, should be able to handle optional divisions (i.e. some sections have subsections while others do not).

This is for an iOS app and my code is written in Objective-C so far.

Answer (score 2):

SQL would certainly be one possibility. If you follow this route, there is a certain trade-off between flexibility and easy of coding which impacts maintainability. For example, if you build a fixed structure, say with some additional levels attempting to cater for the future, such as:

```
Book
  Chapter
    Section
      Sub-section
        Paragraph
```

you will have code with unambiguous references, such as `section.fk_chapter`, `paragraph.fk_subSection`, etc. This will make it easier to troubleshoot and build queries. However you have the problem of having to refactor your code a fair amount if you wanted to add, say, sub-paragaphs, or sub-sub-sections. Your UI will be simpler to code in this approach as you always know which "level" you are working at. Alternatively, you can go for a hierarchical approach:

```
Book
  Chapter
    Content Item
      Content Item
        Content Item
          ....
```

where the contentItem table has a self-reference foreign key. This has the quite big advantage of allowing you any number of levels. Some attribute on the Content Item could tell you the name and "type" of level you are at if needed. It is definitely much more flexible, but will come with some complexity in implementation and UI presentation. columns called `contentItem.fk_contentItem` to refer to the parent level do not tell the coder where they are in the hierarchy. Queries will be a bit more difficult to write. The UI will have to cater for "any" number of levels. But on the other hand, these problems are not insurmountable and many have gone before you on this route.

Your question is quite broad, so opinions will vary on the approach and the above is admittedly very general.